# concat columns in pandas dataframe (json format, multiple conditions, skipping nan values)

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, concatenation, conditional-formatting

I have a dataframe of users coming from 2 postgresql tables that I need to insert into another database. In this one, there is a fixed number of columns. All additionnal information is to be saved in a "champs_addi" column. The champs_addi column is to be in jsonb format in ²postgresql.

For example I need to add the not null values of id_1 and id_2 skipping NA values to champs_addi in this :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'nom': ['sireesha', 'ravi', 'rohith', 'pinkey', 'gnanesh'],
    'prenom': ['mary', 'jack', 'mark', 'someone', 'anothersomeone'],
    'id_1': [98, np.nan, 32, np.nan, 23],
    'id_2': [1, 12, 78, np.nan, 87],
    'champs_addi': [np.nan, np.nan, '{"statut": "actif"}', np.nan, np.nan],
})

#my id needs to be integers -> conversion
for col in df.columns[df.isna().any()].tolist():
        if df[col].dtype == 'float':
            df[col] = df[col].astype('Int64')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebFOr.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie8DC.jpg)

if all cells are null, I can use something like that :
`df['champs_addi']='{"id_1": "'+df["id_1"].astype(str)+'"}'`

I tried using iloc, for loop and other stuff but get lost in the multiple conditions. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Your proposed output is not valid JSON. Try testing it on jsonlint.com

Comment: Yes it's not valid json format but it works when uploaded in my postgresql database whereas using json functions return an error when uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import json


def add_to_champs_addi(g):
    id_1 = np.nan if pd.isna(g["id_1"]) else json.dumps({"id_1": str(int(g["id_1"]))})
    id_2 = np.nan if pd.isna(g["id_2"]) else json.dumps({"id_2": str(int(g["id_2"]))})
    ca = g["champs_addi"]

    s = pd.Series([ca, id_1, id_2])

    if s.isna().all():
        return np.nan

    return " ".join(s[s.notna()])

df["champs_addi"] = df.apply(add_to_champs_addi, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        nom          prenom  id_1  id_2                                        champs_addi
0  sireesha            mary  98.0   1.0                       {"id_1": "98"} {"id_2": "1"}
1      ravi            jack   NaN  12.0                                     {"id_2": "12"}
2    rohith            mark  32.0  78.0  {"statut": "actif"} {"id_1": "32"} {"id_2": "78"}
3    pinkey         someone   NaN   NaN                                                NaN
4   gnanesh  anothersomeone  23.0  87.0                      {"id_1": "23"} {"id_2": "87"}
```

---

EDIT: With columns as a parameter:

```py
import json


def add_to_champs_addi(g, columns):
    cols = [
        np.nan if pd.isna(g[c]) else json.dumps({c: str(int(g[c]))}) for c in columns
    ]
    s = pd.Series([g["champs_addi"], *cols])

    if s.isna().all():
        return np.nan

    return " ".join(s[s.notna()])


columns = ["id_1", "id_2"]

df["champs_addi"] = df.apply(add_to_champs_addi, columns=columns, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works with a fixed column name. I need to be abble to use the column name as a variable in my function, which is not possible with the apply method, is it? (this function is to be used to multiple dataframes with different column added to "champs_addi")